# How do I hook up my ajax request to the events?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I've created the two functions below that get what I need from my API.  But I can't figure out how to get it into the 'events' section of my fullCalendar instance.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.fn.CalendarEvents = (function () {
    return $.ajax("/api/exams/", {
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON.stringify(this),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data, status, XHR) {
            callEvents(data);
        }
    });
});
```

this is my callback function:

```
function callEvents(response) {
    var calObj = [];
    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
        var evt = {
            title: item.title,
            start: item.startDateTime,
            end: item.endDateTime
        };
        calObj.push(evt);
    });
    return calObj;
    //this writes out exactly what I need to go into my calendar
    console.log(calObj);    
};
```

From the examples, I see that they use a JSON feed from a URL or an XML file, but I just need the javascript object that I create in the above functions.

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        //What do I put here?
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs `events` can be specified as a function:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: getCalendarEvents
...


var getCalendarEvents = function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax("/api/exams/", {
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON.stringify(this), // Not sure what you are trying to do here
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response, status, XHR) {
            var calObj = [];
            $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                var evt = {
                    title: item.title,
                    start: item.startDateTime,
                    end: item.endDateTime
                };
                calObj.push(evt);
             });
            // You have to execute callback that is provided in the arguments
            // with your events data
            callback(calObj);
        }
    });
};
```